# how to get a particular block in an array get copied in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, pattern-matching

I have details like below in an array. There will be plenty of testbed details in actual case. I want to grep a particular testbed(TESTBED = vApp_eprapot_icr) and an infomation like below  should get copied to another array. How can I do it using perl ? End of Testbed info can be understood by a closing flower bracket }.

```
TESTBED = vApp_eprapot_icr {
   DEVICE = vApp_eprapot_icr-ipos1
   DEVICE = vApp_eprapot_icr-ipos2
   DEVICE = vApp_eprapot_icr-ipos3
   DEVICE = vApp_eprapot_icr-ipos5

   CARDS=1GIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=3GIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=10PGIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=20PGIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=40PGIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=ETHFAST,ETHFAST
   CARDS=10GIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=ETH,ETHFAST
   CARDS=10P10GIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=PPA2GIGE,ETHFAST
   CARDS=ETH,ETHFAST,ETHGIGE

}
```

I will make it simpler, please see the below array

```
@array("
student=Amit {
Age=20
sex=male
rollno=201
}
student=Akshaya {
Age=24
phone:88665544
sex=female
rollno=407
}

student=Akash {
Age=23
sex=male
rollno=356
address=na
phone=88456789
}
");
```

Consider an array like this. Where such entries are plenty. I need to grep, for an example student=Akshaya's data. from the opening '{' to closing '}' all info should get copied to another array. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have shown what looks like code, but not Perl. There is no array there. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Do you have one line of this per array element? Do you have one block each per array element? Show us a dump (use Data::Dumper) of your data structure, and also explain what you have already tried to do and how it is not doing what you want.

Comment: TESTBED= ssipsec {
 
     DEVICE=sqa-kr3-ssr1
     DEVICE=sqa-kr2-ssr1
     DEVICE=sqa-kr3-se1
     DEVICE=N2X_SSR
 
 CONNECTION-D=40PGIGE,sqa-kr3-ssr1.ethernet 1/4,sqa-kr2-ssr1.ethernet 5/13
 
 # Connection between SSR & N2X
 
 CONNECTION-D=40PGIGE,sqa-kr3-ssr1.ethernet 1/10,N2X_SSR.4103/12
 CONNECTION-D=40PGIGE,sqa-kr2-ssr1.ethernet 5/11,N2X_SSR.4109/13
 CONNECTION-D=40PGIGE,sqa-kr3-se1.ethernet 1/1,N2X_SSR.4103/14
 
 
 
     CONNECTION-D=40PGIGE,sqa-kr3-ssr1.ethernet 15/2,sqa-kr3-ssr1.ethernet 1/2
 
 }
 }

Comment: The array contents will look like above comment. I'm copying a file to an array. There will be plenty of testbed details like above in the array. If I want to copy the only part given above what to be done is my question.

Comment: Please don't dump code into comments. It is almost impossible to read. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40546728/edit) to add any extra information. What you have shown us is not Perl code. What do the contents of your Perl array look like?

Comment: it is not perl code. This is my contents I'm storing in an array. From this i want to grep and store details starting from TESTBED = vApp_eprapot_icr { to till it encounter }.

Comment: I don't know how we can make it any clearer to you. If we can't see your data structures then we can't help you manipulate those data structures. We are not mind readers. How is this data stored in an array? Is there one of these records in each element? Is it one line per element? How are we supposed to know that if you don't tell us?

Comment: People are very happy to help you on this site. But you have to help us to help you. If we ask for more information, it's not to trip you up or to delay answering, it's because we need more information in order to help you.

Comment: DaveCross - whatever I have given above is the array. I have copied and pasted from an array output as such. This is how it will be :(

Comment: I'm not well experienced in perl. Just a beginner. This data is stored in an array like below: @array=`cat <file path>`; So however it was given in the file exactly it is been copied to array too. The above is what I got as output after I tried printing @array.

Comment: See that's the kind of information we were looking for. If you're loading your file into the array like that then each line will be in a separate element of the array. And that's not particularly useful. It would be better to have one of your TESTBED sections in each element. And to achieve that we need to know more about the format of the data file. Is there blank line between the end of one section and the start of the next?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
  print if /TESTBED = vApp_eprapot_icr/../\}/;
}
```

as a sidenote `<>` will capture the filename you use on cmdline. So if the data is stored in a file you will run from commandline

```
perl scriptname.pl filename.txt
```

Comment: The OP seemed pretty clear that he had the data in an array. So I'm not sure how reading from `<>` is going to help. Also, `<>` does not "capture the filename you use on cmdline". You might be thinking of `$ARGV`.

Comment: He actually did not make everything very clear, in the comment he said `The array contents will look like above comment. I'm copying a file to an array`. So could be that he is creating array from a file?

Comment: @Gerry: yes, you are right. I'm not directly using a file. What I want is to copy the file contents into an array then from there have to extract what ever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. We finally have enough information to come up with an answer. Or, at least, to produce two answers which will work on slightly different versions of your input file.

In a comment you say that you are creating your array like this:

```
@array = `cat $file`;
```

That's not a very good idea for a couple of reasons. Firstly, why run an external command like `cat` when Perl will read the file for you. And secondly, this gives you one element in your array for each line in your input file. Things become far easier if you arrange it so that each of your `TESTBED = foo { ... }` records is a single array element.

Let's get rid of the `cat` first. The easiest way to read a single file into an array is to use the file input operator - `<>`. That will read data from the file whose name is given on the command line. So if you call your program `filter_records`, you can call it like this:

```
$ ./filter_records your_input_data.txt
```

And then read it into an array like this:

```
@array = <>;
```

That's good, but we still have each line of the input file in its own array element. How we fix that depends on the exact format of your input file. It's easiest if there's a blank line between each record in the input file, so it looks like this:

```
student=Amit {
Age=20
sex=male
rollno=201
}

student=Akshaya {
Age=24
phone:88665544
sex=female
rollno=407
}

student=Akash {
Age=23
sex=male
rollno=356
address=na
phone=88456789
}
```

Perl has a special variable called `$/` which controls how it reads records from input files. If we set it to be an empty string then Perl goes into "paragraph" mode and it uses blank lines to delimit records. So we can write code like this:

```
{
  local $/ = '';
  @array = <>;
}
```

Note that it's always a good idea to localise changes to Perl's special variables, which is why I have enclosed the whole thing in a naked block.

If there are no blank lines, then things get slightly harder. We'll read the whole file in and then split it.

Here's our example file with no blank lines:

```
student=Amit {
Age=20
sex=male
rollno=201
}
student=Akshaya {
Age=24
phone:88665544
sex=female
rollno=407
}
student=Akash {
Age=23
sex=male
rollno=356
address=na
phone=88456789
}
```

And here's the code we use to read that data into an array.

```
{
  local $/;
  $data = <>;
}

@array = split /(?<=^})\n/m, $data;
```

This time, we've set `$/` to `undef` which means that all of the data has been read from the file. We then split the data wherever we find a newline that is preceded by a `}` on a line by itself.

Whichever of the two solutions above that we use, we end up with an array which (for our sample data) has three elements - one for each of the records in our data file. It's then simple to use Perl's `grep` to filter that array in various ways:

```
# All students whose names start with 'Ak'
@filtered_array = grep { /student=Ak/ } @array;
```

If you use similar techniques on your original data file, then you can get the records that you are interested in with code like this:

```
@filtered_array = grep { /TESTBED = vApp_eprapot_icr/ } @array;
```